# Appropriate choice of force constant of spring to use for Steered molecular dynamics

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling

As per Boltzmann distribution, the variance, or the fluctuation in length squared is given by $$\sigma^2 = \frac{k_BT}{k_{spring}}$$

Since $k_{spring}$ determines how strong the force I am applying to pull, I was wondering how can I determine the appropriate value of $k_{spring}$ I need to use to let the atom/atoms I am pulling vibrate at their thermal fluctuation value. Is there any rule of thumb, or a way of determining this force constant? Thanks.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?